# Inherit ViewController Class of Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm having xviewController which is using XiB in a framework .I copied that framework in my project 
I also import the module in my class but unable to inherit that class in my project view Controller.

For ex:
In my Project
class projectController:UIViewController

I replace UiViewController with framework Controller

Class projectController:xviewController

it is giving error use of undeclared xviewController please help me what I have to do did I make wrong framework

Comment: Have you imported your framework yet?. **example** `import Foundation`

Comment: @ZonilyJame yes I have imported

Comment: in your `.swift` **file**, have you imported your framework? You need to import it in every file you will use it. `import YourFramework`

Comment: yes I'm doing that. Problem is if I making NSObject type  class in framework it is easily using but when I'm making using UIViewController type class in framework it is not using

Comment: Could you add more code in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check for access modifier may be classes of framework are  private.